# Can initial values to this ODE give arbitrarily far blow-up?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem
$$\cases {y''=y^2+x^2\\
y(0)=0 \\
y'(0)=b}
.$$

> Given $T>0$, Is there always an initial speed $b$ such that the solution will be defined at time $T$?

Or is it possible that all solutions will blow-up uniformly in time?
Proofs of continuous dependence on initial values do not seem exclude the possibility that all solutions diverge at the same time, some to $+\infty$ and some to $-\infty$.

Comment: What has $f$ (in the first sentence) got to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: @user10354138 Now deleted.